# ERROR: ".Content was unexpected at this time." while installing poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-poetry

I am trying to install `poetry` in my windows system.
The command that I am using is `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -` 
From official docs [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).

However, I`m getting the following error.
Earlier I used the same command it worked fine but somehow its not working this time.

Error:

```
C:\Project_Files\project>(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -
.Content was unexpected at this time.
```

If anyone from the community could support would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched the terminal from `cmd` to `powershell`.
This solved the issue for me.

Using cmd:
[image]
Using powershell:
[image]

In the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) its mentioned we should use powershell to run the installation command.

```
**USEFULL INFORMATION:**
I tired it works fine with cmd as well you just have to open cmd with admin rights.
```

[image]

**Also try the following if that doesn`t work for you :-**

Firstly make sure you have python installed in your system.
Command to check python: 1)python --version 2)python.exe - this should open the interactive console.

And as mentioned on the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).
If you have installed Python through the Microsoft Store, replace `py` with `python` in the command above.
Also please refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4845), there are multiple solutions provided.

Comment: The documentation **tells you** that this version of the command is for Powershell, and it should also be obvious to anyone with a passing familiarity with either Powershell or `cmd`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel for mentioning this. But according to me, we should have this on the platform. Bcz somehow I missed that, someone else could miss it too & if anyone encounters the same error msg they would find the solution easily. Rather then googling it here and there & wasting time to do hit and trial. 
Perhaps lets wait for other reviewers and if multiple people gives down vote I`ll remove this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, just for your knowledge. We can install poetry using cmd as well, but we have to open cmd with admin rights.

Comment: I'm aware, because I installed it using `cmd` back when I used Windows. Didn't need admin rights (for per-user installs), either. However, the Powershell instructions on the website are Powershell specific. This question isn't a question about how to write code; it's about how to understand the UI *on the python-poetry.org website*, which is why I voted to close.